# caching font-face fonts

Tags: font-face, browser-cache

I'm using @font-face to embed a font hosted on TypeFront, but my font is not cached by the browser (Firefox 3.6.13 and Epiphany 2.30.2). This is causing a FOUC (Flash of Unstyled Content) on Firefox and MFOMT (Momentary Flash of Missing Text, I just made that one up) on Epiphany every single time the page loads (I'm Ok with a FOUC/MFOMT the first time the the page loads, but not everytime).

I'm trying to avoid having to embed the font in CSS in Base64 if possible and I can't host the font myself.

Why is the font not cached? Are there any alternative free font hosting service that does not have this problem?

Test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TypeFront Cache Test</title>
        <style>
            @font-face {
                font-family: "Journal";
                src: url("http://typefront.com/fonts/825588825.ttf") format("truetype");
            }
            h1 {
                font-family: "Journal";
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test text</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I observe in Firebug, the Net tab shows that the font is served with "200 OK" every time the page loads, instead of "304 Not Modified" or other indications that a cached font are being used (e.g. the browser not even attempting a HTTP request).

HTTP headers:

```
Response Headers

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 26 Feb 2011 12:57:18 GMT
Content-Type: font/ttf
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Status: 200 OK
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="typefront_735a460727.ttf"
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Expires: Sun, 26 Feb 2012 12:57:18 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip

Request Headers

GET /fonts/825588825.ttf HTTP/1.1
Host: typefront.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686 (x86_64); en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: null
```

Comment: There is no if-modified-since header in the request, so the server does not have the option to say "not modified". The issue is with the client: why does it send a request at all since there is an Expires header in the future? Why no if-modified-since header, and/or no If-None-Match header? Okay, that can be explained, there is no etag in the response, so it's timestamp based but that should be sufficient, and there is no Last-Modified so no if-modified-since either. But again, the (far) future expires header should prevent any (second) request from taking place anyway.

Comment: I have MFOMT also in Firefox but, as I noticed, this is due to having Firebug active. No Firebug => 304 on fonts (locally delivered).

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE Nov-2016**: The Coral content distribution network, described below, is no longer in operation.

---

This is a rather generic "solution". There is a production service, operating since years, open to the public (though check their terms for commercial use, I don't know if it fits). It is a US federally funded research project in a content distribution network.

It is called [Coral](http://www.coralcdn.org/) and works by appending `.nyud.net` to **any** URL, for example

```
http://www.example.com/static/MyFont.ttf
```

becomes

```
http://www.example.com.nyud.net/static/MyFont.ttf.
```

There is nothing else to do. On the first request, the Coral servers fetch and cache the file (expect some delay), and then they serve it without checking again (they only check infrequently for new versions).

It is using an advanced DNS extension, `DNAME` records, so it might not work with very old operating systems or DNS resolvers, though anything reasonably recent is known to work. This way, requests are routed to a geographically close server.

Comment: This is no longer a valid answer.

Comment: coralcdn.org still seems to be online, but true, the service no longer seems to work, thanks for the heads-up