# Do browsers need to re-download customized fonts every time they access a website..?

Tags: fonts

Earlier today I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884947/do-browsers-need-to-re-download-customized-fonts-every-time-they-access-a-websit) question (the very question which has no answers and of which this is a duplicate), but probably because it was 2 am, nobody answered the question and it seems to have been forgotten. So can you give a look at it and hopefully answer it. Apologize for this question being not a real question but just a redirect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do browsers need to re-download customized fonts every time they access a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884947/do-browsers-need-to-re-download-customized-fonts-every-time-they-access-a-websit)

Comment: I know that this is kinda a duplicate of that question, but since nobody answered it and the question has been forgotten I Decided to remind of such a question.

Comment: This is not considered appropriate usage of stack overflow. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255095/correct-action-for-a-repost-of-recent-question  and here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82271/how-to-move-up-bump-questions-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

WebFonts are no different from any other file type.  So technically they are loaded every time, **but** like other files they are likewise cacheable at many levels throughout.  So it depends on the caching strategy defined by the server hosting the webfile.

As an example, if you download a font from a CDN, the hope is that your users may already have accessed(aka loaded) the font file in the past, and it would therefore be in their local cache, or in a server/router cache somewhere.

As another example, if you're building an int**ra**net website using webfonts from a CDN then you can see large performance increases, because the first time the font is loaded it is probably cached in the corporate network, etc. which means that the request doesn't have to go all the way back out to the CDN every time someone loads your page.  Even the CDN has caching strategies that enable them to serve the file from memory, instead of having to read a physical file.

If by "customized" you mean that you've made or changed the font file and you're hosting the actual files from the same host/server as the html page that uses them, then you'll need to configure your web/application server so that cache expiry settings for font-files are far in the future.  That would allow them to be cached as I mentioned above.